# powershell tfs VersionControlServer service is null

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am trying to use via poweshell the TFS VersionControlServer

```
$tpc=[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsCollectionUrl)
$service = $tpc.GetService([type]"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer")
```

unable to figure out why the variable $service is null

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? Unless you are using a very old version of TFS or are using a feature that isn't exposed via REST API, there have been REST APIs available that are much easier to use from PowerShell available since TFS 2015.

Comment: I am using tfs 2017